# Laravel 8 API testing without middleware

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to test my Laravel API. I've written some simple tests which POST and GET data. These tests work as expected if I run `php artisan test` through the terminal but fail to run correctly when implemented into git hooks with the package called Husky. It runs on `pre-push` the test command, and returns:

```
  • Tests\Feature\ApplicationsTest > retrieve application
  Expected status code 200 but received 422.
  Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 422.
```

I've tried adding:

```php
$this->withoutMiddleware();
```

And this isn't working, what am I missing in my test file...

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ApplicationsTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    /**
     * Retrieve an application
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testRetrieveApplication()
    {

        $response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ])->json('GET', '/api/application/some-id');

        $this->withoutMiddleware();
        $response->assertStatus(200)->assertJson([
          'success' => true
        ]);


    }

}
```

Comment: where are you posting data? from Laravel 422 is usually a validation error

Comment: To my endpoint. Unlikely a validation error because the error is not present when running `php artisan test` directly from the terminal. Only when plugged in with [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky)